# Can I assign two buttons to a same action or outlet in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have created a user interface for iPhones in the 'w Compact h Any' tab in the interface builder. I then decided to make a different interface for the iPad version of the app, in 'w Regular h Regular', but when dragging the buttons and labels to the actions and outlets in my ViewController.h file, they replace the buttons and labels in the other interface.

Is there any way I can preserve both at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click+drag *from* the `IBAction` method's little connector circle straight *to* another control in your storyboard, even if it's already been connected to one (and actually I think you can drag from the storyboard object to the `IBAction` too).

[image]

Just keep in mind if you're using different classes, you'll probably want to use `id` and check the class name before you do stuff with it:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        //
    }
}
```

To verify that it's connected to both, click the method circle:

[image]

If you're writing Swift in Xcode 7 or 8, the method created will use the `Any` type; you'll need to change it to `UIButton` in order for this to work:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    //                                  ^
}
```

Comment: Just as an update for Xcode 8, if you created the first `IBAction` by dragging from the storyboard, it's possible you may have forgotten to change the defaults and it probably created it with a sender of `Any` and this will not work.  Just change `Any` to `UIButton` and this will work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign same action for two button  by giving tag to each button but you cant give same outlet for two buttons.

For example :

suppose you have two buttons like as below:

```
  UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:(YourFrame)];
    btn1.tag=1;
   [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:btn1];

  UIButton *btn2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:(YourFrame)]; 
   btn2.tag=2;
  [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:btn2];
```

then

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ((sender.tag=1))
    {
      // btn1 clicked, do something for btn1 click action here...
    }
    else if ((sender.tag=2))
    {
      //btn2 clicked, do something for btn2 clik action here...
    }
}
```

this is for programatically buttons but if you are doing it using storyboard then same procedure is for that .

Comment: Thank you! How may I do it if I have buttons as outlets then?

Comment: if you have button as outlets suppose you have button outlets like         IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
IBOutlet UIButton *button2;    You can set tag as button1.tag=1,button2.tag=2  in viewDidLoad or  you can set it in storyboard. To do that select your button from storyboard and from right side set  its tag.